# How to access state object within render function error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a react-native app and am having an issue accessing state within render.

I can console.log the state (this.state) and it will show log what's expected.

If I console.log something like... (this.state.value) it will error even though the value is present.

I can't figure it out and I've been trying all day!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Loader from '../common/loaders/Loader';
import Header from '../common/header/Header';
import moment from 'moment';
import number from '../../utils/numbers';
import dateLabel from '../../utils/dateLabel';

// Content
import i18n from '../../i18n/i18n';

// Actions
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from '../../actions/authActions';
import { loadingBegin, loadingFinish } from '../../actions/loadingActions';
import { accountsList } from '../../actions/accountsActions';

// Services
import { getAccounts } from '../../services/account';
import { getTransactions } from '../../services/transaction';

// Styles
import common from '../../styles/common';
import styles from './styles';

// --- --- ---
class Home extends Component {

state = {};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if (!this.props.auth.authenticated) this.props.navigation.navigate('Unauthorised');

    this.props.loadingBegin();

    this.state = {
    accounts: [],
    balances: null,
    categories: null,
    transactions: null,
    meta: null,
    };

    this._bootstrapAsync();

    this.props.loadingFinish();
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    navigation.addListener ('willFocus', () =>{
    console.log('RE-RUNNING PAGE');
    });
}

_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    // Grab the filter values
    // TODO -> Put filters into Redux store
    this.filters = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('filters'));

    // Check to see if we have any accounts already added
    // Get the accounts info and prime the redux store and state
    const accounts = await getAccounts(this.props.auth);
    this.props.accountsList(accounts);
    this.setState({
    accounts,
    });

    // If there aren't any accounts, redirect to add an account
    if (this.state.accounts && this.state.accounts.length === 0) this.props.navigation.navigate('AccountsNone');

    // Grab the latest transactions and set the state (to be used later)
    let transactionsOptions = {};
    if (this.filters && this.filters.filtersForm) {
    // date set period
    if (this.filters.filtersForm.dates) transactionsOptions.date_type = this.filters.filtersForm.dates;
    // dates between
    if (this.filters.filtersForm.fromDate && this.filters.filtersForm.toDate) {
        transactionsOptions.date_from = this.filters.filtersForm.fromDate;
        transactionsOptions.date_to = this.filters.filtersForm.toDate;
    }
    }
    if (this.filters && this.filters.accountSwitches && this.filters.accountSwitches.length > 0) {
    let obj = this.filters.accountSwitches;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (data.accountSwitches[key]) {
        if (!transactionsOptions.account_ids) transactionsOptions.account_ids = {};
        transactionsOptions.account_ids += ',' + key;
        }
    });
    };

    console.log(transactionsOptions);

    let transactions = await getTransactions(this.props.auth, transactionsOptions);
    let meta = transactions.meta;
    let data = transactions.data;

    const balances = this.state.transactions.Balances.map((value) => {                
        return {
            label: moment(value.date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM Do"), 
            value: value.amount
        }
    });

    const categories = this.state.transactions.Categories;

    this.setState({ 
    transactions: data,
    meta,
    balances,
    categories,
    });
};

render() {
    const { ...props } = this.props;
    const loading = this.props.loading.inProgress;
    let body;

    if (loading) {
    body = <Loader visible={loading} />;
    } else {
    body = (<View>
        <Text style={[styles.balancesDate]}>nuffink</Text>  
    </View>);
    }

    console.log('state.TRANSACTIONS');
    console.log(this.state); // <----------------this works
    console.log(this.state.transactions); // <----------------this doesn't work
    console.log('state.TRANSACTIONS //');

    return (
    <ScrollView
        style={[common.body, styles.container]}
        ref='_main'
        contentContainerStyle={{
        flexGrow: 1
        }}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
    >

        <Header {...props} txt={"DASHBOARD"} />

        <View style={[common.containerPadding, styles.balances]}>
        <Text>{this.state.trasnactions.value}</Text> <--------------- kills the app and my soul
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
    )
}

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
const { accounts, auth, loading } = state;
return { 
    accounts,
    auth,
    loading
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { accountsList, loadingBegin, loadingFinish, loginUser, logoutUser })(Home);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Text>{this.state.trasnactions.value}</Text> <--------------- kills the app and my soul
```

Appreciate the humor lol. What is happening is your component, like all components will render a single time without any data unless already available in your state or props. Which means all the logic you do in your event handlers and componentDidMount will not take affect until the component has rendered at least once. ie: you have no data to work with in your scenario.

Which is why when you try to access this.state.transactions.value on the inital render, it kills your app, because there's no data at the start and you're trying to render a falsey value.

To workaround this you can add some extra logic like this which checks if transactions is truthy.

```
{this.state.transactions ? 
   <Text>{this.state.transactions.value}</Text>
: null }
```

Comment: Thanks! 

I tried your suggestion but it's not working for me. 

body = (<View>
        <Text style={[styles.balancesDate]}>nuffink</Text>  
        {this.state.transactions ? 
          <Text>${this.state.transactions.meta.Criteria.DateType}</Text>
        : null }
      </View>);

I wonder if there's another issue - perhaps connecting the store?

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting from this line?

Comment: {this.state.transactions ? 
          <Text>${this.state.transactions.meta.Criteria.DateType}</Text>
        : null }

It actually doesn't error any longer (which is a positive step! - thanks) but it's not outputting a value. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Sorry about that, remove the "$" and it should be a bit more clear what error we are getting. It also could just the that Criteria.DateType does not return any value. Do you have some sample data that displays what that value actually is?

Comment: Actually, I missed the error on the console. No red screen was making me think it was all 'working'. It's complaining about this...

02-12 23:08:27.933 14516 15993 W ReactNativeJS: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
02-12 23:08:27.933 14516 15993 W ReactNativeJS: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.transactions.Balances')

It's not liking this line for some reason... const balances = this.state.transactions.Balances.map((value) => {

Comment: Ah cool. so it looks like we got passed the initial error with this.state.transactions, since now we are able to executing your bootstrap_async method. That means the app successfully rendered the first time and now its going through the rest of your logic. You can pretty much apply the same logic we used for this.state.transactions now in your other method. It's checking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `this.state.transactions` is null to start off with (set in the constructor), and you can't access the property of something that's undefined. Also, you misspelled "transactions" in your render function, inside the `<Text/>`.

One way to solve this is in your render check whether `this.state.transactions` is defined before trying to access `this.state.transactions.value`, e.g.

`{this.state.transactions && <Text>{this.state.transactions.value}</Text>}`

Comment: Thanks for that. I made the spelling mistake when changing the example for the site - sorry! I've tried the check but it's not working unfortunately. Something along the lines of...

this.state.transactions.something.somethingelse

...is the value I need.

Also, doesn't the _bootstrapAsync function overwrite the null value held in state? Or should I initialise in a different way?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Nothing renders? If there's an error, what specifically is it. And yes, `_bootstrapAsync` overwrites it, but as the name says is *async*, meaning while it's running the component continues to mount and render. So it renders before that function has finished executing, and so it will initially render with transactions as null.

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment. It's not outputting a value even when I add a check for value. For example... {this.state.transactions ? <Text>${this.state.transactions.meta.Criteria.DateType}</Text> : null } It's not showing an error but it's also not showing me the value from state. Good point about the async func. Thanks!

Comment: @user3303836 and if you print `this.state.transactions` in render, once it's populated, is there a `.meta.Criteria.DateType` property in the object? I assume it'd just be a string. Make sure you have the right property path, capitalisation of keys, etc.

Comment: No, `this.state.transactions` comes back as `null`. So I can't interrogate the obj. The value is supposed to be a string (if it existed). :(

Comment: @user3303836 oh ok so that's why nothing is rendered. In that case, the problem must be with the async function not properly fetching/setting the data. You'd have to look into that, though that's probably another question.